# Concurrent system modeling tools

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm currently taking a course in concurrent software design, and we're focusing a lot on modeling.  I see the value in this, but I am not sure if the tool we are using is horrible, good, or somewhere in between, because I can't find any other examples.  We're currently using LTS Analyzer, with some more information [here](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/).

So my question is, for anyone who has done concurrent system design, do you model you application before implementing, and if so what tools do you use to do so?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used is myself I've heard some good things about [JPF](http://javapathfinder.sourceforge.net/) (planning to use it soon).

Answer (score 1):

One of the more widely known tools for modelling & verification of concurrent/distributed systems in various industries is the SPIN model checker: http://spinroot.com/spin/
However keep in mind that no matter how correct your design and/or verified your model is, your implementation still needs to follow suit. This is where many projects fail in one way or another.